# Laravel database error during artisan migration

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.5

I am trying to learn Laravel 5.5 and am stuck with an error while using `php artisan migrate*` and cannot figure out the solution. The error that I am getting is attached as image below.

[image]

Comment: show ur migration code

Comment: It's seems you have violated the rule of sql. please add your migration for the table.

Comment: Found the solution guyz. thanks for the effort :)

Comment: can you add the migration code?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry Guyz. Got the answer. I was trying to use **"string" type** as **"unsigned"** whereas it should had been **"integer" type**.

Thanks again for everything.

Comment: Then it's better to close the question :D